# Automatic error passing on async functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I have some `async` function that awaits some promises inside which may get rejected, and I want to pass on all errors to the function's returned promise. Does JS do this automatically?

For example:

```
async foo(){
  bar_result = await bar();
  baz_result = await baz();
  return 'ok';
}

foo()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

What would happen in the above example if either `bar()` or `baz()` get rejected? Intuitively, they would be caught at the `.catch(console.error)` line...

My alternative idea is to surround the function's contents in a `try` block and then `catch(err){ throw err; }`, but it looks redundant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside an `async` function, if a Promise is `await`ed, and that Promise rejects, the function will immediately terminate, and the Promise that it returned will reject (with the same value of the rejected `await`ed promise). Your function will work as desired - if either `bar` or `baz` rejects, `console.error` will result in the rejection being logged (and `console.log` will not be called).

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I have been trying to get proof of this from some documentation.

Comment: That's just how `await` works - you can try it yourself for different `bar`s and `baz`s if you want. If you want to see the official description of its functionality, you can [browse through the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#await), but it's pretty dense.